# Jquery Mobile - on initial load of website the data-role="controlgroup" doesn't display correctly

Tags: jquery, mobile

Sample code below displays as a single multi button on all pages unless the page is loaded directly not via ajax. So the first time the site load, the buttons display as 3 individual buttons, but after that initial load, it displays correctly. This applies to any page I load the website from. Runs jquery mobile 1.2.0.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align:center;">
<a href="tel:0000000000" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Call Us</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com/" data-icon="star" data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-theme="b">Full Website</a>
<a href="https://login.website.com/" data-icon="gear" data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-theme="b">Login</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 1.2.0 to 1.3.2 solved the issue :/